# Portion of expression could not be parsed: AND

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gql

I know this is basic, but I just can't get a select statement with an AND in the where clause to work in GQL.  I've boiled the problem down to this

SELECT * FROM entity WHERE acctName == 'Company 1' AND acctID == 87896657

I get

Portion of expression could not be parsed: AND acctID == 87896657

If I change the order of the AND the message appears for the second item acctName.  If I run the select with each of them alone it works fine.  This all indicates that the problem is with the AND.  GQL must support AND, right?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Didn't realise it permits `==`, I thought it was just `=`: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html. But if the conditions work separately, I guess that's not it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE acctName = :1 AND acctID = :2", "Company 1", 87896657)
```

Answer (score 1):

The questioner must be asking for the problem in Java. If it is the case, you should take a look at this post 
[GQL error on WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903474/gql-error-on-where/7492310#7492310)