# GQL error on WHERE

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

```
select from comments.Comment 
where ownerType == 'looks.Look' 
AND ownerName == 'Yakuza' order by date
```

I get exception:

```
Portion of expression could not be parsed: AND ownerName == 'Yakuza'
```

While this query works nice:

```
select from comments.Comment 
where ownerType == 'looks.Look' 
order by date
```

And this too:

```
select from comments.Comment 
where ownerName == 'Yakuza' order by date
```

The full code:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
String query = "... query goes here ...";
List<Comment> comments = null;
try {
    comments = (List<Comment>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
}
...
```

Comment: Could you share the actual code you are running?  At least how you're building the query string.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Note this isn't GQL - it's JDOQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace "AND" with "&&"

```
  PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  try {
    Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + Song.class.getName()
        + " where mArtist== '" +artist+
        "' &&  mTitle=='"+title+
        "' &&  mAlbum=='"+album+"'" );
    List<Song> list = (List<Song>) query.execute();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    throw e;
  } finally {
    pm.close();
  }
```